# Get Active Directory Information with ASP.NET without username and password

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get users' Active Directory information on the local network, from an ASP.NET Web Application. The Web Application is running on an `IIS` on the local network.

What I want: When users log into the website, they can see their name, surname, username, email and picture from Active Directory. The problem is, when they enter their website, the web application is asking for username and password. Users have already entered their username and password when turning on their PCs. So they shouldn't need to do it again.

Users login to PCs with their username and password.
I can get domain and username with:

```
string adInfo = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

Also I can get Active Directory info on my local PC on debug when testing `System.DirectoryServices`, but when other users try this web app in local, the username and password dialog appears.

How can I make it so that users are able to enter their website without entering their username and password?

I tried all samples here, but I can not find any solution. I think I am missing some important things.

Comment: I would like build a web application like sharepoint Person.aspx <div> "s4-bodyContainer". User's picture and name will appear on top of web site without entering his name and password. Because user is already login with his name and password

Comment: I found a solution with setting Internet Explorer. İnternet Expolorer > Internet Options > Security > Custom Level > User Authentication > logon > Automatic logon with current user name and password. But Firefox or Chrome users need to enter username and password. Also this is not possible to set every users' Internet Explorer's settings

Comment: Correct only IE can do pass through of active directory credentials, however in the case of Firefox and others if users login at the credentials prompt with domain\username and their normal windows password this will mirror what IE does/can do when configured in the way that you describe

Answer (score 14):

you need to use *Windows* authentication mode for your website.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" /> <!-- disable anonymous authentication -->
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

... and then use LDAP query under current user's context to get extended information about the user:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM"))
using (var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de))
{
  ds.Filter = string.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
  ds.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new [] {
            "sn",  // last name
            "givenName",  // first name
            "mail",  // email
            "telephoneNumber",  // phone number
            // etc - add other properties you need
            });
  var res = ds.FindOne();

  foreach (string propName in res.Properties.PropertyNames)
  {
    ResultPropertyValueCollection valueCollection = res.Properties[propName];
    foreach (Object propertyValue in valueCollection)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Property: " + propName + ": " + propertyValue.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the current user has read access to active directory, not all installations allow this, you may have to consider running your app pool with a service account that Is either in the domain admin group or similar to provide access. This needs do be done carefully for obvious security reasons

Answer (score -1):

Hey this is rather a suggestion than answer to your question. Never ever will browsers allow you to bypass their security system. So the username and password box are unavoidable. What i would say is get the username,surname,and all that you want from the user and save it in a cookie that has really long expiry date. So the next time the user logs in, read that cookie and display what you want. Provide them with an option to change it if they want.

This is the best solution that should work most of the time.