# ASP.NET Active Directory

Tags: asp.net

Ive tried some of the answers people have given all over but I cannot seem to get it right.  I have an asp.net web form and windows authentication working.  But how can I get user information from AD like a full name and display it on the web page?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Active Directory Information with ASP.NET without username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841302/get-active-directory-information-with-asp-net-without-username-and-password)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current user's Active Directory details in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637486/11683)